# Stopped receiving AIB bank code notifications

Tags: notifications

I have recently stopped receiving notifications from my bank and one card company when they send me codes to log on to their sites on the PC.  I have a Huawei PSmart 9 phone and I am on 02 network.  Both the bank and 02 are saying that it is not their end causing the problem.  I have searched through the internet and tried every thing on my phone settings but nothing works.

Comment: Just for clarification, is it sent as an Android notification, or SMS? Also, did you recently change the phone? If it's an Android notification, since the Huawei and Google debacle, it might be possible that the bank app is using Google's push notification, and for the device to receive it, it needs to have updated Google Play Service. If it's an SMS, then it has something to do with the mobile carrier.

Comment: No Andrew I haven't changed the phone.  I will contact the bank and ask what way they send their notifications and act accordingly. Ta

Answer (score 1):

After 9 months of having this problem I was finally given a solution today from a lovely gentleman in AIB. I had tried everything!!! I rang them every month, called into the branch, checked with phone provider etc. It was a case of change my phone or my bank.
Here’s what worked for me.
Go to your messages. In the top right hand corner there should be three dots. Click on them. There will be a selection of options. Click on spam and blocked. My AIB messages were coming up as blocked. There were about 50 of them there. Click that AIB is not spam.
Best of luck